# Returns Undefined Instead Of Value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a page that is supposed to display some data fetched by AJAX from a database, but instead it displays an error message.

The page that shows the data:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
      mysql_select_db("databasename");

      //$niftystocks=array();

      $sq="SELECT TPNTCode FROM `niftystock`";
      $r=mysql_query($sq);

      $i=0;
      while ($ro=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
          //array_push($niftystocks,$row['TPNTCode']);
          $tpnt=$ro['TPNTCode'];

          $sql="SELECT * FROM `nsepricequotes_latest` where TickerPlantCode = '$tpnt' ";
          $rs=mysql_query($sql);
          $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

          if ($i == 0)
              echo "--" . $row['DateTime'] . "--";
          $sy=$row['Symbol'];
          echo "<span id='txtHint'></span><a href='#'><span onmouseover='showUser()'>$sy</span>: " . $row['LastTradedPrice'] . " (" . $row['PercentChange'] . ")</a>";
          if($row['PercentChange'] >= 0)
              echo " <img src='http://mastertrade.in/master/ticker/images/arrow-up.gif' border='0' > | ";
          else
              echo " <img src='http://mastertrade.in/master/ticker/images/arrow-down.gif' border='0' > | ";
          $i++;         
      }
    ?>
```

getinfo.php:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET['q'];
echo $q;
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);
$sql1="Select OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice from nsepricequotes_latest WHERE Symbol like '".$q."' "; 
while($row1= mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    $openprice=$row1['OpenPrice'];
    $highprice=$row1['HighPrice'];
    $lowprice=$row1['LowPrice'];
    $tpnt=$row1['TickerPlantCode'];
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM 52wkhighlow WHERE nFTCode = '$tpnt'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wkhigh=$row['BSE52WkHighVal']; 
    $wklow=$row['BSE52wlLowval']; 
}  

?>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Open Price</td><td><?php echo $openprice; ?></td>
        <td>High Price</td><td><?php echo $highprice; ?></td>
        <td>Low Price</td><td><?php echo $lowprice;?></td>
        <td>52 Week High</td><td><?php echo $wkhigh;?></td> 
        <td>52 Week Low</td><td><?php echo $wklow;?></td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

> -undefined Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mastertr/public_html/master/ticker/getinfo.php on line 11

Comment: Please read the docs. You're using `mysql_fetch_array` incorrectly, and the docs have an example of what you should be doing.

Comment: sorry but the last one was not editing

can you please explain am not getting

Comment: @ĦāwťlįcįOuxRâwkstärßøį Exactly which part is throwing the error?

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Comment: Don't use [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/) unless you're writing a DB administration program; select only the columns you need.

Comment: Instead of executing multiple queries in a loop using data retrieved from a previous query, use a [join](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-join-sql-tutorial/).

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, concise and representative. What's posted has too much extraneous code.

Answer (score 2):

because you didn't run your `$sql1` query

set this :

```
$sql1="Select OpenPrice, HighPrice, LowPrice from nsepricequotes_latest 
       WHERE Symbol like '". mysql_real_escape_string($q)."' "; 
$result_1 = mysql_query( $sql1 );
```

then start :

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_1) )
```

instead of :

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1) )
```

Comment: its running here
fetching data from database

$sql1="Select OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice from nsepricequotes_latest WHERE Symbol like '".$q."' "; 
while($row1= mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
$openprice=$row1['OpenPrice'];
$highprice=$row1['HighPrice'];
$lowprice=$row1['LowPrice'];
$tpnt=$row1['TickerPlantCode'];
}

Comment: i tried now am getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in /home/mastertr/public_html/master/ticker/getinfo.php on line 12

Comment: parse error generated when you missing something like `}` or semicolumn etc.

Comment: its showing parse error in line no 12 
line no 12 is
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_1) )

Comment: first thing edit the given code according to your requirenment like your getting the fetched result with `$row1` then you should have to use `$row1` instead of `$row`, and if you again get the error then plz re-edit your code with changes

Comment: edited code here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952387/returns-undefined-instead-of-value-ajax-javascript


please check

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to run `mysql_query()`

```
$sql1="Select OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice from nsepricequotes_latest WHERE Symbol like '".$q."' "; 
while($row1= mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
```

should be something like

```
$sql1="Select OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice from nsepricequotes_latest WHERE Symbol like '".$q."' "; 
$res = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row1= mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

Comment: look preciously mysql_query() has used

Comment: @ĦāwťlįcįOuxRâwkstärßøį You query probably just failing for some reason. What's the value of `$q`? And are you sure you don't need to escape it?

Comment: the value of $Q is ACC 

the edited code is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952387/returns-undefined-instead-of-value-ajax-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In your mouseover there's the following:

```
showUser()
```

Note that undefined and "" is not the same.

```
if (str=="")
  {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
```

The above doesn't work because str is undefined and not an empty string.
Either do this:

```
showUser("")
```

Or do this:

```
if (str == undefined)
```

Comment: i tried with if (str == "undefined") but am getting the same undefined